# Whilst using EntityFramework 6.1.1 Task Extensions 'ToArrayAsync' the await never returns

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have been writing a WebApi service which is async top down and have discovered an odd behavior with one of my entity framework queries. We are using Entity Framework 6.1.1 and the query itself is relatively straightforward:

```
var companyRoles = await model.Memberships.Include(m => m.Role)
            .Where(m => m.UserProfileId == guid).Select(cr => new { Membership = cr, cr.Role }).ToArrayAsync(); 

... rest of the method excluded for brevity
```

Naturally this call is encapsulated in an async Task with an enumerable return type. At the time that the query is executed, we can see the call being made using SQL Profiler (and when captured and executed in isolation returns the expected result), however the ToArrayAsync() materialization in code never returns. We can leave this hanging for several minutes with no discernible error or information.

Contxt: this method itself is called within an async WebApi controller method and it appears that if we remove the async part of the **nested** method call this query executes and returns fine.

In the above part of the api there is no other database processing, this is the only thread running in the system (this is on my local development machine) and is also consistent in its behaviour.

I've tried removing the 'Select' materialization from the above query and it still fails so it isn't that. Has anyone seen this behavior before? It seems very much related to the async keyword but I get no exceptions or clues. Any suggestions very welcome! SQL Server 2014, VS2013 Update 3, High-End PC (i7). It really looks like a deadlock in its appearance, but I can't see what it would be being deadlocked with!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the overall stack of async calls look like, from the top-level application entry point to this EF method?  It's possible that you're deadlocking the synchronization context somewhere along the way.

Comment: Also, be sure to check the value of `httpRuntime.targetFramework` in your web.config; it should be `4.5`.

Comment: httpRuntime.targetFramework definitely set at 4.5 but definitely worth checking thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have used await operator outside DbContext using scope.

I had a following method:

```
    public Task<Entity[]> GetAsync()
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            return context.Entities.Where(e => e.Status == Status.Pending).ToArrayAsync();
        }
    }
```

I was awaiting for it like this:

```
await GetAsync()
```

and this line never returns. Then I've changed the implementation and put `await` operator **inside** `using(context)` scope:

```
    public async Task<Entity[]> GetAsync()
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            Entity[] es = await context.Entities.Where(e => e.Status == Status.Pending).ToArrayAsync();
            return es;
        }
    }
```

That solved this issue for me.

Comment: This is a good answer to a different question, but probably not to this question: the OP does correctly use `await`. The question shows what the code looks like: `var companyRoles = await [...].ToArrayAsync();`.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no solution to this post then I want to write that I had same problem and got it to work using ToListAsync()

I also had this issue with nested queries and had to make it as two queries.